# Sum of JSON values

Tags: json, postgresql

Is there a nicer way to sum JSON values in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT SUM(j.value::int)
  FROM json_each_text('{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::json) AS j(_, value);

 sum
-----
  3
```

Comment: Define nicer: shorter/custom function ...?